# Chaining AJAX requests - Angular 2 and ES2015 Promises

Tags: ajax, typescript, angular

In Angular 1 I could do something like:

(pseudo code)

```
/* part 1 */
function myFn1(){
    var x = $http.get('myurl');

    x.then(
        () => {}, // do something here
        () => {} // show error here
    );

    return x;
}

/* part 2 */
myFn1().then(()=>{
  $q.all($http.get('url'), $http.get('url2'), $http.get('url3'))
    .then(()=>{  /* do something */  });
});
```

I know how to replicate part 1 in Angular 2

```
let myFn = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        this.http.get('myurl')
            .subscribe((success) => {
                // do something here
                res(success);
            }, (error) => {
                // show error here
                rej(error);
            });
    });
}
```

However the code in 2nd example looks much uglier and much less readable for me.

**Question 1:  Can I do it better/nicer way?**

Following that logic I can wrap all GET requests (part 2) in promises and than chain it but again this doesn't seem to be nice and clean way of doing that.

**Question 2: how I can nicely chain requests in angular 2 without wrapping every single request in promise.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for part2, you can still use Promises:

```
myFn1().then(() => {
  return Promise.all(
    $http.get('url').toPromise().then(res => res.json()),
    $http.get('url2').toPromise().then(res => res.json()),
    $http.get('url3').toPromise().then(res => res.json())
  ).then(() => {
    /* do something */
  });
});
```

Comment: Do I need any specific version of angular to achieve that? Right now compiler throws `'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'` and I currently on rc2

Comment: You just need to import toPromise operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'`.

Comment: That did the think. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage observables for this. It's not necessary to use promises...

**In series** (equivalent to promise chaining):

```
this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap(data => {
      // data is the result of the first request
      return this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.json());
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      // data is the result of the second request
    });
```

**In parallel** (equivalent to `Promise.all`):

```
Observable.forkJoin([
  this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.json()),
  this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.json())
])
.subscribe(results => {
  // results of both requests
  var result1 = results[0];
  var result2 = results[1];
});
```

Regarding error handling and part1, you can migrate things like this:

```
/* part 1 */
function myFn1(){
  return this.http.get('myurl').map(res => res.json())
     .map(data => {
       // do something
       return data;
     })
     .do(data => {
       // do something outside the data flow
     })
     .catch(err => {
       // to throw above the error
       return Observable.throw(err);
     });
}
```